# Mocking an Angular Service that has RxJS Observables for testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, sinon

I wish to Mock a service I have build in my Angular App. My service is below:

```
@Injectable()
export class WizardDialogNavigationService {

  public navAction$: Observable<any>;
  public navActionSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor() {
    this.navAction$ = this.navActionSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public navAction(action: string): void {
    this.navActionSubject.next(action);
  }
}
```

I use this in a component where I inject it into my constructor and then add it to a subscription in the OnInit method, for example (component code) - my code is below, notice I only add what is relevant.

```
private navSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

constructor(private wizardDialogNavigationService: WizardDialogNavigationService) {}

public ngOnInit(): void {
       this.navSubscription.add(this.wizardDialogNavigationService.navAction$.subscribe((direction) => {
      this.moveMaterialStepper(direction);
    }));
  }
```

I need to Mock my service to test my component, however I am going around this the wrong way, for instance, I create the mock service like so...

```
class MockWizardDialogNavigationService {

public navAction$: Observable<any>;
public navActionSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
// this is wrong?
constructor() {
    this.navAction$ = this.navActionSubject.asObservable();
  }

  public navAction(action: string): void {
    // how do I mock a .next?
  }
}
```

The class is at the top of my test file (spec.ts), I then add it in the providers object

```
{provide: WizardDialogNavigationService, useValue: MockWizardDialogNavigationService},
```

and later add a stub so I can listen for when the navAction method is called:

```
stubWizardService = sinon.createStubInstance(WizardDialogNavigationService);
```

However I feel this is wrong, I am usure how I declare the navAction$ observable in the mock and when running my tests I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object
>   (evaluating 'this.wizardDialogNavigationService.navAction$.subscribe')

Could someone perhaps explain what I need to do to Mock the service and prevent the error? If I haven't explained myself well or more code is required please let me know. I know very little about testing and am trying to learn.

Comment: Asking the same question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46688100/3001761) and [again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46689914/3001761) and deleting it isn't likely to get you an answer. The Angular docs include an example of testing components that rely on async services: https://angular.io/guide/testing#test-a-component-with-an-async-service

Comment: Just read the guide then....

Answer (score 0):

It's import to mock both the service and the service call. You not want to use the real promise cause it deals with async and can fail. You can mock errors to.

This is an example how you can mock your service.

```
it('should mock videos', inject([VideoService], (videoService: VideoService) => { 
        videos = [
            { id: 0,  name: 'Superman' },
            { id: 1, name: 'Superman part 2' }
          ]
        spyOn(videoService, 'videos').and.returnValue(videos); 
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.getVideoOne()).toContain(Superman);

      });
```

Answer (score 0):

After the advice of @jonsharpe I found that the problem - I removed the Mock Service class and created a stub instance like so

```
MockWizardDialogNavigationService = sinon.createStubInstance(WizardDialogNavigationService);
```

I kept the service in the providers array

```
{provide: WizardDialogNavigationService, useValue: MockWizardDialogNavigationService},
```

then I declare the navAction$ like so

```
TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
// some code removed
        stubWizardService.navAction$ = Observable.empty();

});
```

everything works!